# DEBUG: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [3] The directory [.next/cache/next-babel-loader] has too many files (greater than 1000)

Tags: google-app-engine

Deploying a NextJs application with a nodejs runtime environment reaches the following error:

`DEBUG: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [3] The directory [.next/cache/next-babel-loader] has too many files (greater than 1000).`

I've searched for a couple of hours and all of the solutions refer to the 10.000 files limit quota of GAE, but none talks about the folder limit.

Neither the Google Cloud quota page for Google App Engine has any information about this by folder limits:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/quotas#Deployments1000

Answer (score 1):

The article which you are referencing is related to resource quotas and not file/folder limits. This document clearly states that there’s a 1000 files per directory limit. Therefore, the error message you are showing is exactly the  intended behaviour. [1]

[1] https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/how-requests-are-handled#quotas_and_limits

Comment: Thanks, so it seems that is not possible with GAW run a NextJs 9 application

Comment: I am assuming your question is unrelated to the original issue? GAE also supports other languages apart from the official ones stated in their documentation via “custom runtimes” [1]

[1] https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/

Comment: I guess is a problem with the App Engine deployment. I didn't get to test the Custom Environment Features. I just create a server and did all the deployment manually